# ¿Porque iis dibuja la pagina hasta que se termina de procesar y wamp la procesa poco a poco?

Tags: php, css3, iis, animación, wamp

Disculpen, uso wamp en mi pc para desarrollar y mi servidor local donde corre todo es iis, el problema que tengo es que hice una animación para mostrar mientras carga una pagina que requiere muchas consultas, en mi pc con wamp funciona muy bien pero en iis se muestra la pagina hasta que ya se cargo por ende ya no se muestra la animación, esto genera mucho tiempo en que el usuario no sabe si realmente esta cargando o no.

¿Hay alguna configuración en iis que tengo desactivada que evita que se muestre la pagina hasta que esta completamente cargada?

Nota, todo en este caso es en PHP.

El código que muestra la animación:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    });
```

Este es el link del servidor, como veran aqui se muestra hasta que se despacho todo y eso evita que se muestre la animación:
https://ec49-201-121-91-22.ngrok.io/pruevas/prueva.php

Este es el link a mi wamp de desarrollo, asi quisiera que se muestre la pagina cargando y la animacion:https://6a58-201-121-161-200.ngrok.io/kenal/pruevas/prueva.php

Les agradezco mucho su apoyo!

Comment: Te toca mostrar el código que muestra la animación porque no es evidente la causa y tu IIS sólo cumple con entregar recursos que le pidas, igual que el Apache en WAMP

Comment: listo, es todo exactamente igual pero en mi pc la pagina va cargando (son varias tablas) y el icono de carga de navegador gira en sentido horario mientras muestra la animacion, en iis ya no, el icono de carga del buscador gira en sentido anti-horario hasta que esta cargada y despliega todo, gracias de antemano

Comment: Nope. El script (PHP) completo. Toca ver cómo estás cargando los JS, las imágenes y eso. Puedes mirar en la consola del navegador. Dependiendo de como esté generando ese PHP el HTML resultante, es posible que el IIS esté sirviendo las cosas en un orden que haga que se vea diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer, apenas cargue tu sitio corres la animación y necesitas obtener el estado actual de tu documento, cuando el documento pase a estado **'complete'**, entonces detienes la animación.

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'complete') {
         document.getElementById('interactive');
         document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility="hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
#loading{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9999;
    background:url("https://media.giphy.com/media/iJOZwC1R7WVxAxs4Gs/giphy.gif") no-repeat center center rgba(0,0,0,0.25)
}
```

```html
<div id="loading"></div>
```

Ten en cuenta que no verás ningúna animación de carga si tu página se carga rápidamente, así que usa este código en una página con un tiempo de carga alto, y también te recomiendo que coloques tu js en la parte inferior de la página.

Comment: Muchas gracias, de hecho ya se muestra mi animación y se quita  al tener la pagina lista sin problema en wamp, pero en iis el navegador (Chrome) se pone a cargar la pagina y la despacha hasta que esta terminada, serviría poner un túnel a mis aplicaciones para que puedas ver como cargan?

Comment: @JaimeRodriguez si, podría ser de ayuda para entender un poco mejor lo que te está sucediendo amigo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, agregue los link, espero puedan ayudarme, este es un problema que por lógica no encuentro una solución!